# Parameterized type as type parameter

Tags: haskell

When compiling this:

```
data Rec t = Rec { intPt :: t Int, doublePt :: t Double } deriving Show

type Pt2 a = (a,a)
type Pt3 a = (a,a,a)

type Rec2 = Rec Pt2 
type Rec3 = Rec Pt3

main = do
      print $ Rec (1,2) (3.4,5.6)
      print $ Rec (1,2,3) (5.6, 7.8, 9.0)
```

I got

```
Unexpected type `t a' where type variable expected
In the declaration of `Rec (t a)'
```

How to make this compile and work?

Comment: I'm downvoting this because I reckon that the code you posted isn't the code that produced that error, which is rather unhelpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I cannot reproduce the exact error message you're reporting, but I can see two issues with your example.

1. You are trying to derive `Show` for `Rec` which is parameterized over a type constructor. This is too hard for GHC to do fully automatically at the moment, but you can make it work in practice by enabling a number of extensions.
2. You are using partially applied type synonyms `Pt2` and `Pt3` as arguments to `Rec`, which isn't permitted. You can work around this by switching to datatypes.

A bit more detail: To solve problem 1, you can say:

```
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving, FlexibleContexts, UndecidableInstances #-}

data Rec t = Rec { intPt :: t Int, doublePt :: t Double }
deriving instance (Show (t Int), Show (t Double)) => Show (Rec t)
```

By using a standalone deriving clause, you can explicitly specify the preconditions on the `Show` instance. In this case, these preconditions require the `FlexibleContexts` and `UndecidableInstances` extensions to also be enabled.

To solve problem 2, you can do the following:

```
data Pt2 a = Pt2 a a deriving Show
data Pt3 a = Pt3 a a a deriving Show

type Rec2 = Rec Pt2 
type Rec3 = Rec Pt3
```

Datatypes can be partially applied, but type synonyms cannot. So using `Pt2` as an argument to `Rec` is only allowed if `Pt2` is a datatype. With these modifications, your main function typechecks (and works):

```
main = do
  print $ Rec (Pt2 1 2) (Pt2 3.4 5.6)
  print $ Rec (Pt3 1 2 3) (Pt3 5.6 7.8 9.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what GHC you're using, but the error in this code is:

```
A.hs:6:1:
    Type synonym `Pt2' should have 1 argument, but has been given none
    In the type synonym declaration for `Rec2'
```

Because type synonyms may not be partially applied, which will be essential for your higher-kinded parameter to Rec2.

Consider using e.g. type families or explicit data instead of type synonyms.